# Android Studio Doesn't work

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build, build.gradle

I create a standard project in Android Studio, but... when I click finish, just doesn't start the project.The main window still there and the project can't see in Recent Project.

If I open recent projects I can see the project o tried to create but empty.

What's happened?

I share 4 photos.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

1 more picture

[image]

Comment: Try creating a project with a different name and update if that works. Also, manually go into the folder where the project is created and check which folders do you miss there.

Comment: Is empty, no files only directories.

Comment: ah. If nothing's working, maybe you can try removing android studio and reinstalling it. Or maybe use a different version.

Comment: Nothing... keep the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to choose a different API to create a project and solve the problem. I usually use API 14, now i start the 90% projects with API 15 and that solve the problem. I hope the answer help another people.